# Is RMAN backup platform independent?

Tags: oracle, rman

I have RMAN backup from AIX server and want to restore on Linux OS. Could you please let me know if there is a way to do it?

Thanks a lot for help in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Query this table in order for you to see the platforms to which rman can convert your**

```
SYS@EMR> select * from V$DB_TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM;

PLATFORM_ID PLATFORM_NAME                                                                                         ENDIAN_FORMAT
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------
          7 Microsoft Windows IA (32-bit)                                                                         Little
         10 Linux IA (32-bit)                                                                                     Little
          5 HP Tru64 UNIX                                                                                         Little
         11 Linux IA (64-bit)                                                                                     Little
         15 HP Open VMS                                                                                           Little
          8 Microsoft Windows IA (64-bit)                                                                         Little
         13 Linux x86 64-bit                                                                                      Little
         12 Microsoft Windows x86 64-bit                                                                          Little
         17 Solaris Operating System (x86)                                                                        Little
         19 HP IA Open VMS                                                                                        Little
         20 Solaris Operating System (x86-64)                                                                     Little
         21 Apple Mac OS (x86-64)                                                                                 Little
```

### Step by Step restore

- Connect to the target database using rman and backup the database -
  Source Node/ System
- copy following files to the Destination node ( backup pieces ,
  control file backup and parameter file)
- Perform the modificaiton on destionation node to parameter file -
  PFILE
- Once the pfile is ready, set the environment parameter and connect to
  rman
- connect to target - start up the db no mount mode
- now restore the controlfile from the backup on destination node
  (which copied from source db )

**Example :**

```
restore controlfile from '/backup/file name';
```

once the restore is complete - mount the db.

- now main step is backup prices which you copied from the source db to destination db catalog themcatalog the backup pieces.
- Now, you need to recover the db - find he sequence number

  list backup of archivelog all;
- Rename the Redologfiles

  alter database rename file
- Now final step is you need to recover the db to the last sequence number

  **Execute this series of statements:**
  set until sequence 123456; -- sequence which you go previous.
      set newname for datafile 1 to '/node2/database/db1/system01.dbf'; -- data file paths modified

  ```
  restore database; 
  switch datafile all; 
  recover database; 
  alter database open resetlogs;
  ```

---

**2** As a second approach this can be done using the **[Oracle Transportable Database](http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/5cb5ed706d254a8186256c71006d2e0a/b1043c7f570e1842862577fe00268c0d/%24FILE/Oracle_Generic_Migration_Version_2.pdf)**  - follow the link for great article form IBM guys !

Answer (score 0):

Use datapump if you want platform independency (windows to linux and vice versa)

exdp
imdp

I can send you my classnotes if you want.
Today's lesson was about datapump lol.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Colin'tHart, seems like a legitimate answer - although not very well prepared.

Comment: Well, my thinking was as follows: the first sentence is OK, but not an answer IMHO, just a comment that datapump is -- or might be possible to be run as -- platform independent, with no information as to how or why this is achieved. The second sentence adds nothing and is wrong. The third sentence is definitely a comment, but I don't know @Ahmed plans to send his classnotes.

Comment: @ypercube yeah sorry for the nonthorough answer. I wasnt at my computer.

Comment: I thought if it was important he could look it up. RMAN according to my mentor isnt as platform independent.. Ill add the exdp and imdp code soon.

Answer (score 0):

rman backups are limited in usability to the ENDIAN_FORMAT as reported in V$DB_TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM.
On Intel platforms it reports Little (as above), on sparc it says Big as expected.
Provided the Linux runs on a big endian platform rman will process the backup files.
11GR2 on AIX on a Power5 CPU reports this as limited to:
IBM zSeries Based Linux
IBM Power Based Linux
If the Linux runs on a Little endian platform you are limited to transportable tablespaces (which is only available on Enterprise Database licenses) or datapump.